# Обработка событий TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, события, tableview

Привет всем, есть editable TableView, редактирование происходит двойным щелчком и сохраняется при нажатии Enter, можно ли сохранять значение не только через enter, а например, при щелчке на другую TableCell или в другую область, то есть при выходе TableCell из фокуса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это реализуемо. Суть в том, что вам необходимо проставить свою `cell factory`, в которой необходимо реализовать данную логику. Код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
TableColumn < TableBean, String > columnId = new TableColumn < > ("Id");
columnId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory < > ("id"));
columnId.setEditable(true);
columnId.setOnEditCommit(event -> {/*some logic here for save new value*/});
columnId.setCellFactory(e - > new TableCell < TableBean, String > () {
    private TextField textField;
    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        if (this.textField == null) {
            this.createTextField();
        }
        this.textField.setText(getString());
        super.setGraphic(this.textField);
        super.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        Platform.runLater(this.textField::requestFocus);
    }
    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        super.setText(String.valueOf(getItem()));
        super.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String s, boolean b) {
        super.updateItem(s, b);
        if (b || s == null) {
            super.setText(null);
            super.setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            super.setText(this.getString());
            super.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }
    }
    private String getString() {
        return String.valueOf(super.getItem());
    }
    private void createTextField() {
        this.textField = new TextField(getString());

        this.textField.setMinWidth(super.getWidth() - super.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        this.textField.setOnKeyPressed(t - > {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || t.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                super.commitEdit(textField.getText());
            } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                this.cancelEdit();
            }
        });
        this.textField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) - > {
            if (!newValue && textField != null) {
                super.commitEdit(textField.getText());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Обратите внимание на метод `createTextField()` : в нем создается текстовое поле и вешается обработчик `focusedProperty()` - при покидания поля будет вызывать метод `editCommit()` с новым значением.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ, Вы очень помогли) С Наступающим!